# A question on short exact sequences.

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

The following is an excerpt from Atiyah-Macdonald on short exact sequences.

[image]

I don't understand the part where the author says "Then $d(x'')$ is defined to be the image of $y'$ in Coker ($f'$)". Is $d$ a mapping from $N'$ to Coker ($f'$)?

Comment: $d$ is a map from $\ker(f'')$ to $\text{coker}(f')$

Comment: @fixedp- Shouldn't there be a mapping from $N'$ to Coker ($f'$)? The line says "image of $y'$ in Coker ($f'$)".

Comment: It's the quotient map $N\to N/\im(f')=\operatorname{coker}$

Comment: @QuangHoang- But ker($f')\not\subset N$!! Your mapping is not defined.

Comment: You *define* the image of $x''\in \ker(f'')$ under $d$ as the image of $y'$ (if you follow the diagram chase, you'd see that $y'$ is dependant on $x''$) in $\text{coker}(f')$

Comment: Sorry, I meant $N\to N/\operatorname{im}(f')$.

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely the snake lemma http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma

the construction of the so called boundary operator $d$ is a little bit tidious but gets very clear after some time.

You have to do a little bit diagram chasing to see that it is defined and well-defined.

Have a look at this short video taken from the movie "It's my turn"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etbcKWEKnvg

Sorry for only being informative and not constructive, but I think the best way for you is to get it straight yourself - maybe with different literature.

Comment: I found learning diagram chasing isn't that easy for a beginner from books, but there're two materials which seems more accessible: Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html), pp115, subsection *Relative Homology Group*, and Eisenbud's *Commmutative Algebra*, pp637, subsection A3.7.